# Multi-Sig bitcoin in testnet

Tags: multi-signature

I am trying out bitcoin multi-sig in test net and when I make a payment i get the payment details address as 3CRrDxJwwkrJqmgSWikQMmZWCDo5SmL3tc

but when i go into my test net wallet and try to send funds to this address it comes back as unrecognised.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Addresses starting with **3** are Mainnet P2SH addresses. For testnet your require a valid base58check/RIPEMD160 encoded scripthash for a P2SH address (starting with **2**).